# For X of Y loop counters

Tags: javascript, mysql, for-loop

I have this `standings` array

```
    { pos: 1, competitor_id: 583, rating: 2049, tier: 1 },
    { pos: 2, competitor_id: 862, rating: 1818, tier: 1 },
    { pos: 3, competitor_id: 67, rating: 1762, tier: 1 },
    { pos: 4, competitor_id: 758, rating: 1750, tier: 1 },
    { pos: 5, competitor_id: 713, rating: 1735, tier: 1 },
    { pos: 6, competitor_id: 868, rating: 1730, tier: 1 },
    { pos: 7, competitor_id: 946, rating: 1706, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 8, competitor_id: 893, rating: 1705, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 9, competitor_id: 731, rating: 1695, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 10, competitor_id: 869, rating: 1692, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 11, competitor_id: 998, rating: 1672, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 12, competitor_id: 968, rating: 1661, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 13, competitor_id: 460, rating: 1656, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 14, competitor_id: 879, rating: 1648, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 15, competitor_id: 969, rating: 1631, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 16, competitor_id: 925, rating: 1629, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 17, competitor_id: 999, rating: 1626, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 18, competitor_id: 991, rating: 1619, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 19, competitor_id: 956, rating: 1618, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 20, competitor_id: 711, rating: 1617, tier: 2 },
    { pos: 21, competitor_id: 964, rating: 1616, tier: 2 },
```

I want to increment `tier` by one every time we move 6 rows down.
As you can see above it switches to tier 2 properly but fails to increment to 3 at pos:13 and to tier 4 at pos:19

I tried

```js
const tiersize = 6;
// setting the counters
let tiercounter = 1;
let limit = tiersize;
// running the loop
for (const row of standings) {
  await connectionPromise
    .query({
      sql: 'update table set tier = ? where competitor_id = ?'
    }, [tiercounter, row.competitor_id], );
  if (row.pos == limit) {
    tiercounter += 1;
    limit += tiersize;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're updating the database, not the array.

Comment: Add `row.tier = tiercounter;` to the loop to update the array as well.

Comment: Thank you, should I add that to the if condition?

Comment: No, it should not be in the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the database, but you're not updating the array as well. Add `row.tier = tiercounter;` to the loop.

```
const tiersize = 6;
// setting the counters
let tiercounter = 1;
let limit = tiersize;
// running the loop
for (const row of standings) {
  await connectionPromise
    .query({
      sql: 'update table set tier = ? where competitor_id = ?'
    }, [tiercounter, row.competitor_id], );
  row.tier = tiercounter;
  if (row.pos == limit) {
    tiercounter += 1;
    limit += tiersize;
  }
}
```

But rather than incrementing `tiercounter` as you go, you can simply calculate it from `pos`.

```
tiercounter = Math.floor((row.pos-1) / tiersize) + 1;
```

The updated code would then be:

```
const tiersize = 6;
// running the loop
for (const row of standings) {
  let tiercounter = Math.floor((row.pos - 1) / tiersize) + 1;
  await connectionPromise
    .query({
      sql: 'update table set tier = ? where competitor_id = ?'
    }, [tiercounter, row.competitor_id], );
  row.tier = tiercounter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @barmar, it still fails to update past tier 2. At this point, I suspect something off in my code that is outside of the scope of my question.
Will revert back as soon as I have spotted the culprit.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! counter is starting at -1 so I guess I will have to initialize it before the loop to 0.

Comment: That was a typo, `- 1` should be `+ 1`. Initializing it before the loop makes no difference, since it's not incrementing.

Comment: It worked flawlessly. Now I can sit back and try to wrap my head around your approach :)
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You were checking row.pos number with limit and the limit you were updating everytime. Which doesn't make sense with the condition. update the if condition as below.

```
    for (const row of standings) {
  await connectionPromise
    .query({
      sql: 'update table set tier = ? where competitor_id = ?'
    }, [tiercounter, row.competitor_id], );
    if (row.pos % tiersize  == 0) {
    tiercounter += 1;
    limit += tiersize; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still retuning same issue...I have to investigate further why tier gets stuck at 2

Comment: I was going to post a similar answer. But doing `limit += tiersize` makes it equivalent to checking the modulus.

Comment: when i try this i am getting expected result. 
 for (const row of standings) {
  await console.log("tiercounter  is " + tiercounter);
    if (row.pos % tiersize  == 0) {
    tiercounter += 1;
    limit += tiersize; 
  }
}

Comment: Is the shared JSON result is pulled after execution of the code ? As far me initially it might have different value and it will be updated at connectionPromise method.

Comment: @Suresh Yes, result awaits for each update to complete and I also checked directly the table and it has same results.

Comment: @Barmar
If that may ring any bell, it only switches to tier 3 at pos: 67...